# Office 2016 - how do I restore ability to close windows by double-clicking upper left of the title bar?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I've been using the ability to close windows by double-clicking the upper left since...well probably Windows 3.1. I just installed Office 2016, and it appears that the Outlook/Word/Excel icon in the upper left of the title bar has been removed and the title bar has been repurposed as the "Quick Access Toolbar". I can't for the life of me figure out to make the icon appear again, I've tried to add various icons to the title bar, but the best I can do is a small separator that gives you a few pixels to click on to close the window.

My ultimate goal is to be able to double click the top left of a title bar in Office 2016 and close the window. Open to workarounds, registry hacks, etc.

[image]

Comment: It's available in Office 2013. [link](https://imgur.com/a/l3amIVl)

Comment: I want to confirm with you that you don't have extra space to double-click the upper left or you just can't use the feature.

Comment: It still works if you can manage to click on the extremely small area to the left of the Save icon.

Answer (score 0):

Double (left) clicking top-left corner closes Word 2016 here as long as its maximized (Office ProPlus x86 on Win10 x64 v1607)?

*Single left-click brings up the apps context menu (similar to right-clicking anywhere on title-bar); so I guess double-click defaults to the bolded entry (acts like hitting Enter key):*

[image: Single left-click brings up the apps context menu]

You can customize that Quick Access Toolbar by right-clicking in top-right, Customize Quick Access Toolbar, change 'Choose commands from:' to All Commands, add a couple Separator & move it to the top to give yourself some space between corner & buttons, but it doesn't seem to change how much of the top-left responds to this so I don't think it'll do you much good.

*Been doing IT support for 10yr+ & I didn't know of this feature :)*

Comment: That is the standard right-click context menu on any application's title bar, which isn't accessed, by double click an icon.

Comment: You are correct, but left-clicking top-left corner brings it up. Double-(left-)clicking that corner does close multiple applications I've tried. Try things before you downvote :(

Comment: You make no mention of a left-click only right-click in the body of your answer.  If you want to indicate that double left clicking, in the blank space, before the save icon closes Word that would be an entirely different situation.

Comment: The right-click was to customize the quick access which probably won't help OP. I clarified, thanks. Noted on voting, sorry.

Comment: So you said "so I don't think it'll do you much good.", if you don't think the solution is helpful, you really shouldn't suggest it.  I have reversed the downvote, but I can't justify an upvote if you don't think your solution will do the author much good.

Comment: My answer was to confirm its working here & the picture was to show what my Word 2016 looks like. Maybe it was a bigger area in older Office versions so I wanted to provide that. Although it wouldn't make the top-left-corner clickable area bigger, it does provide spacing between buttons that OP may not want there. Maybe they have a disability? I am just providing options...

Comment: That's basically the issue - while the double-click to close behavior still works (and thus is still mostly supported), the area you can realistically click on at the top isn't more than a couple of pixels so it's nearly impossible to hit it. I was hoping there was some sort of option or even registry hack to make that clickable area larger.

Comment: Please edit your question to expand what you're looking for because two other people are confused what your end-game is. I'm guessing you might not get what you want (since Show Desktop bottom-right got downsized too), I'd try some other options if possible. Maybe advise in your question you're open to other solutions, but make sure to note any requirements (keyboard only, mouse only, limited keys/clicks, etc.)

Comment: Thanks gregg, I edited the question to hopefully provide more context. It's just something that's hard to explain since a lot of people aren't familiar with the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following things to get more extra space.

1.Right click on somewhere in the top left corner and you can see these options：
[image]

2.Choose the gray option in the image above and you can see:
[image]

And now you get enough extra space.

Comment: This still doesn't work - double clicking in the upper left will resize/maximize the window (as if you double clicked anywhere else on the title bar). There is still a tiny spot on the very left hand corner that you can double click to close, but it's only a few pixels wide.